# Posting static form with no input fields

Tags: javascript, c#, web

I am very new to web development and am confused about submitting my form data.  I know how to submit and retrieve data when using the  tag in my html and wrapping in in a , but in this case I have a static html page displaying data in tables where the user is able to edit and modify the table input.  How do I post the values on this form when none of the fields are of the type input?

Comment: you could create hidden input fields in runtime using javascript and add them to the form element, or use ajax

Comment: You can use Ajax to send data to the server. I'm just curious, if you have no "input" elements were is your data stored? Can your access this data from JS? If you can, making an ajax request (or even using the fetch api if you're targeting modern browsers) should be singing easy to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can post form data via javascript if you are generating the data on the fly. JQuery have the Ajax function that simplifies this process. E.g.,

```
    function post_form_data() {
        var data = {
            data1: "something,
            data2: "something else"
        };
        var url = "https://someurl.com/api/v1/etc";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: data,
            success: function() {
               // do something, like transition to 
               // a different page or something
            },
       });
    }
```

Call post_form_data() whenever you wish to do a post. In practice you may include the form data in function parameters or extract them from other sources.

To see all the detailed ajax, please read up on [jQuery Ajax Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

On click of javascript button you can create a form and submit it:

```
let form = document.createElement('form');
form.action = 'http://yourdomain/youraction';
form.method = 'POST';

form.innerHTML = '<input name="inputs" value="test">';

// the form must be in the document to submit it
document.body.append(form);

form.submit();
```

Instead of input value test, specify a JSON value here.

This would POST form to the provided URL.

Hope this helps.